# Why am I getting Json Malformed Exception?

Tags: json

I'm trying to make a program using json to save user registers to file, but when I try to read my json I get the error "JSON malformed". This is my code to write in json:

```
    Gson gsonObject = new Gson();
    FileWriter writerFile;

    try {
        writerFile = new FileWriter("users.json", true);
        writerFile.write(gsonObject.toJson(writerUser));
        writerFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I use arrays to be easy modify the values (only take the json back to array and make my modify) but i can't reader this json file after writer, this is my reader code:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<User> userList;

    try {
        BufferedReader readerUserList = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.json"));

        userList = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(readerUserList, User[].class));

        for (User user : userList) {
            System.out.println(user.toString());
        }
```

And after that i get "json malformed" error, where is my error?

If help you guys, inside my json file is my arrays like that:

```
[{"name":"james","idCode":1}][{"name":"kyle","idCode":2}][{"name":"test","idCode":3}]
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. A JSON file can only have a single top level element. Yours has 3.

Comment: How is your object "writerUser", before you use "gsonObject.toJson()"?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Gson... but your json file has format problems, it is supposed to look like this:

```
[{"name":"james","idCode":1},{"name":"kyle","idCode":2},{"name":"test","idCode":3}]
```

The problem is not when you try to read, but when you write it.

Comment: I see, you know a way to fix my write method?